# unable to have a result while calling a rest API with Swift

Tags: swift, rest

I try to make a small command line program in swift 5 to call a Rest Web service

```
func callRest() {

    URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)

    let todoEndpoint: String = "http://myURL"
    print (todoEndpoint)
    guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        exit(1)
    }

    // private let apiKey = "my API Key"
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "API-Key": "my API Key"
    ]

    var session = URLSession.shared
    session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        print ("task")
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }

        // check the status code
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            print("Error: It's not a HTTP URL response")
            return
        }
        print (httpResponse)
    }

    task.resume()

    // Response status

}
```

```
print ("debut")
callRest()
print("fin")
```

And I never see a result...
the line `print ("task")` is never display

Any help appreciate.
I think I don't really understand the task.resume usage...
(same code work in a playground)

Comment: Do you have a main.swift file?

Comment: yes, it is just a small sample, every thing is in the main.swift file

Comment: " small command line program "? Your object might be released too soon. Async task in CommandLines causes issue because "app" might exit too soon.

Comment: that what I suspect

adding a sleep, resolve the problem ....